# iPhone - Post on Friends wall

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect

hi I am using FBConnect to post on users wall.... But is there a way I can post on friends wall??

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can post onto walls from the API, but you can publish to their [Stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#stream).

Answer (score 1):

Due to many of errors and many of negative comment about Open Graph API in facebook ios 6. facebook remove the " Post to friends wall via the API ". You can only use the fbconnect of ios 5.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"100004925467891", @"to",
                           @"http://pri.com/pit.png", @"picture",
                           @"http://pr.com", @"link",
                           @"Data", @"caption",
                           @"data",@"description",
                           @"Birthday Reminder",@"name",nil];
[[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But if u Post to own wall Open Graph API is still working.